# Web Scraping Nested Loop in Python is Too Slow

Tags: python, selenium, performance

I've written up a Python script using Selenium to help me order an RTX 4090 (figured it was the only way to beat the scalpers) but at the moment it is far too slow. This is primarily because of a nested while loop that I'm using to run through a couple of popup pages on BestBuy without getting completely hung up. I don't have a lot of experience, so I'm not sure what a better option would be for dealing with these issues. At this point it takes far too long to click the add to cart button. Any advice for making this more efficient would be greatly appreciated. Below is a link to the nested loop in question and the code block (should've added that first my bad).

[Nested While Loop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y6trB.png)

```
#Imports basic selenium libraries and driver
from selenium import webdriver as wd
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select

#Imports fake_useragent library
from fake_useragent import UserAgent

#Imports driver
import undetected_chromedriver.v2 as uc

#Imports and initializes nordvpn-switcher
from nordvpn_switcher import initialize_VPN,rotate_VPN,terminate_VPN
hideIP = initialize_VPN(stored_settings=0,save=0,area_input=['United 
States'])
rotate_VPN(hideIP)

import time
import random

#Function to pause the bot for a random number of seconds and print the 
time elapsed
def randomSleep():
random_wait_time = random.randrange(1.0,5.0)
time.sleep(random_wait_time)
print("Paused For: " + str(random_wait_time) + " Seconds")

#Function to pause the bot between page refreshes for a random number of 
seconds and print the time elapsed
def randomRefresh():
random_refresh_time = random.randrange(30.0, 90.0)
time.sleep(random_refresh_time)
print("Paused For: " + str(random_refresh_time) + " Seconds")

uc = uc.Chrome()
uc.implicitly_wait(10)

rotations = 0

#Loop refreshes website until add to cart button is available and changes VPN connection after 5 refreshes    

while (True):
try:
    while (True):
        try:
            while (True):
                try:
                    uc.get(url)
                    country_select_button = uc.find_element("class name", 'us-link')
                    country_select_button.click()
                    break
                except NoSuchElementException:
                    break
            survey_close_button = uc.find_element("xpath", '/html/body/div[7]/div/div/div[3]/button[2]')
            survey_close_button.click()
            break
        except NoSuchElementException:
            break
    add_to_cart_button = uc.find_element("xpath", '/html/body/div[4]/main/div[3]/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/div[14]/div[2]/div/div/div/button')
    add_to_cart_button.click()
    break
except NoSuchElementException:
    print("Out of stock. Waiting for refresh.")
    rotations+=1
    print("Has Refreshed " + str(rotations) + " Time(s)")
    if rotations % 5 == 0:
        rotate_VPN(hideIP)
    randomRefresh()
```

Comment: add your code to your question.  In general questions like this don't get much traction.  but maybe you will get some suggestions.  But most folks will not respond unless the code is in the post.

Comment: The code should be visible through the hyperlink at the bottom but I can paste it in as well if that would help.

Comment: Share your code not an image.

Comment: Are you using **Implicit Wait**?

Comment: The scalpers are probably using better tools already... Post a minimal reproducible example of your code: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I use implicit wait just after the chrome instance is loaded, yes, but no where in the loop itself. I'll add the code as well just didn't have time to format it in the question box at that moment - sorry.

Comment: I think you are using lot of while loops. replace them with explicit wait for the element. just need one for loop I guess. remove all implicit waits and sleeps. Remember Explicit is better than implicit always.

Comment: Cool, I'll check out explicit waits instead. The popups only occur some of the time. If I remove 2 of the loops how do I make sure it continues even if an element is not found?

Comment: on the explicit wait you can put a timeout.  that will allow you to move on if it never shows up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Why it is to slow?

As you using

> implicitly_wait(10)

First It try to locate element if it not found it will wait for 10 second every time in whole program

You are also using try and except so, what is going here is first it goes to try block if the element is not found it will wait for 10 second as you implemented implicitly wait and then it will try again to locate element as it is not present in page at last after 10 second wait it will goes into except block. It wait for 10 second in every while loop so the program became too slow.

**Solution 1:**

Remove implicitly wait for try and except block using below code:

`implicitly_wait(0)`

**Solution 2:**

Use [Explicit Wait](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/explicit-waits-in-selenium-python/) instead of implicitly wait